# Can i redefine the checkmark in a PDFLaTeX CheckBox

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

My problem: I want to create an active PDF (formula) that contains checkboxes. The checkboxes should have a "cross" as "checked" indicator, not the sign that comes as default. How can this be achieved ?
Note : I still use an "active" CheckBox here, so re-defining the whole thing won't work.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `checkboxsymbol` option. Suitable numbers for the symbols can be found in the `pifont` documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox[checkboxsymbol=\ding{56}]{Check }
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned that i already did this. The problem comes when i open the produced PDF file in "Preview" (i am on Apple ... Then the old default symbol shows up...

Comment: then ask a new question with the correct problem description (and a suitable minimal example).